# What is the pattern for this date format?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

You can't parse a timestamp without knowing the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern first and I'm not sure what this would be:

> 1980/01/30 10:36:42 -0400

I think it would be something like `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`, but I'm not sure about the `-0400` part or if I should be capitalizing `MM` and `HH`.

Comment: If your last 5 characters are always going to be the same timezone, then chop it off using substring (or equivalent)

Comment: `-0400` would be the time zone, `GMT - 4`.  The month should be capitalized, but without more information, it's difficult to know how to treat the hour, but in the absence of the am/pm mark, it would be a reasonable guess it's 24 hour representation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MM` is months, `mm` is minutes

`HH` is 24 hour time, 0-23 `hh` is 12 hour time

`Z` is the timezone, the final field you're looking for

In the [API documents here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), there's a lovely table listing all of the pattern letters.

Answer (score 0):

[`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is documented here. You can parse that date with something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws ParseException {
  String date = "1980/01/30 10:36:42 -0400";
  String pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
  System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));
}
```

Output is (because my system is in EST) -

```
Wed Jan 30 09:36:42 EST 1980
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user this format for your date formate

```
 SimpleDateFormat   date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd:HH:mm:SS Z");
 System.out.println(date);
```

**output**

```
2012/1/16:16:11:31 -0400
```

Answer (score 0):

From **javadoc** :The following examples show how date and time patterns are interpreted in the U.S. locale. The given date and time are 2001-07-04 12:08:56 local time in the U.S. Pacific Time time zone.

```
     Date and Time Pattern                 Result

"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"  2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"                  Wed, Jul 4, '01
"h:mm a"                            12:08 PM
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"         12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"K:mm a, z"                     0:08 PM, PDT
"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"  02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"    Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"                 010704120856-0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"    2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
```

`RFC 822 time zone:` For formatting, the RFC 822 4-digit time zone format is used represented by `z`